# Actualizar matriz de objetos en mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy usando mongoose e intento actualizar varias propiedades de un objeto filtrado por `_id`dentro de una matriz de objetos...
He probado varias opciones y esto es lo que tengo ahora pero no funciona.

El modelo

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { 
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    surname: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  usertype: { type: String, default: 'user', required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  direction: {
    street: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  telf: { type: Number, required: true },
  avatar: { 
    name: { type: String, required: false },
    ext: { type: String, required: false },
  },
  birthDate: { type: Date, require: true },
  comments: [{
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: [{ type: String, required: true }],
  }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
});

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  return hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

/** Variable virtual string con nombre completo */
UserSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function () {
  return `${this.name.name} ${this.name.surname}`;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Consulta

```js
const userid = "5d410c56db0203190ca90dfe"
const loginusername = "María Dolores Serena";
const newtext = "Editado desde programa externo"
const newtags = "noSqlBooster update comment!"
const commentid = '5d41c3cedf58f82eb4c6f6df'

db.users.updateOne( 
    // Filter
    { _id: userid },
    // Update
    { $set: { 
        "comments.$[elem].user": loginusername,
        "comments.$[elem].text": newtext,
        "comments.$[elem].tags": newtags,
    } },
    // Options
    { arrayFilters: [ { 
        "elem._id": commentid,
      } ],
    }
);

/* Devuelve
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 0,
    "modifiedCount" : 0
}
*/
```

**Actualización :**
Utilizando un programa externo consigo realizar bien la consulta. Solamente debo de especificar cuando me refiero a un `_id` como `ObjectId(_id)`.
Pero cuando intento aplicar esto en mi aplicación con Mongoose me indica que `ObjectID` no es una función, pese a importarlo desde mongoose.

En el programa externo la consulta exitosa la realizo así:

```js
db.users.updateOne( 
    // Filter
    { _id: ObjectId(userid) },
    // Update
    { $set: { 
        "comments.$[elem].user": loginusername,
        "comments.$[elem].text": newtext,
        "comments.$[elem].tags": newtags,
    } },
    // Options
    { arrayFilters: [ { 
        "elem._id": { $eq: ObjectId(commentid) },
      } ],
    }
);

/* Respuesta
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 1,
    "modifiedCount" : 1
}
*/
```

En mi código lo incorporo así sin éxito.

```js
const { ObjectID } = require('mongoose').Types;

User.updateOne( 
    // Filter
    { _id: ObjectID(userid) },
    // Update
    {
      $set: { 
        'comments.$[elem].user': loginusername,
        'comments.$[elem].text': newtext,
        'comments.$[elem].tags': newtags,
      }, 
    },
    // Options
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ 
        'elem._id': { $eq: ObjectID(commentid) },
      }],
    },
  );

/* Respuesta en consola de depuración
(node:1516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: ObjectID is not a function
    at Object.query.updateComment (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\src\controllers\users_queryes.js:181:12)
    at ctrl.editComment (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\src\controllers\users.js:359:28)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at helpers.isAuthenticated (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\src\helpers\auth.js:10:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (c:\Users\pedro\Desktop\Plataforma_Operativa_servicios_seguridad_privada\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
warning.js:18
(node:1516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
warning.js:18
(node:1516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
warning.js:18
*/
```

Comment: Hola, viendo la definición de tu modelo, veo que haz resumido los campos. ¿Podrías colocar un ejemplo completo de los campos de tu modelo? Por lo visto los documentos insertados en tu `array` de `comments` al parecer disponen de un campo `_id`. ¿Has considerado la posibilidad de crear una referencia a una colección llamada `comments`? Saludos

Comment: He editado añadiendo la definición del modelo completo. Seguramente acabe por crear una nueva colección para los comentarios. Pero de momento me parece más adecuado dejarlo así y ya tengo curiosidad por saber como resolver el problema. Respecto a lo del _id. Yo acabo de empezar con Mongodb y tengo bastantes lagunas. Pero por lo que veo, tras definir el modelo, las nuevas incorporaciones al array 'comments' añaden auntomáticamente un _id como si de un documento a parte se tratara. Además me surge la duda de si estos '_id' pueden coincidir con los '_id_ ' de los comentarios de otros usuarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he solucionado el problema...
La consulta me funciona perfectamente de esta manera.

```js
const { ObjectId } = require('mongoose').Types;


query.updateComment = async (
  {
    commentid, userid, loginusername, newtext, newtags, 
  },
) => {
  const resp = await User.updateOne( 
    // Filter
    { _id: ObjectId(userid) },
    // Update
    {
      $set: { 
        'comments.$[elem].user': loginusername,
        'comments.$[elem].text': newtext,
        'comments.$[elem].tags': newtags,
      }, 
    },
    // Options
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ 
        'elem._id': ObjectId(commentid),
      }],
    },
  );
```